# No consigo hacer una query en laravel usando eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo la tabla user:

```
-id 
-name
-email
```

Tengo la tabla task:

```
-id
-title
-description
-active
```

Y tengo la relacion nxm de estas:

```
-id
-task_id
-user_id
-finish_date
```

#### User.php

```
 public function tasks()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class,'tasks_x_users')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('finish_date');
}
```

#### Task.php

```
 public function users()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'tasks_x_users')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('finish_date');
 }
```

---

La query que pretendo hacer es : 'Obtener las tareas activas  en las que todos los usuarios asignados a la tarea tengan el campo `finish_date` no null' para asi saber que tareas han sido completadas por todos sus participantes.

Lo primero que he hecho ha sido esto:

```
$tasks = self::whereHas('users')->where('active',true)->get();
```

Con esto me trae las tareas que tiene al menos un usuario asignado, pero ahora estoy intentado ver como ver si el `pivot (finish_date)` no este null en este conjunto por cada tarea. Pero no se si ponerlo con subquery o no se.

---

#### Caso practico

Imaginense que tengo 2 tareas.

```
1 - Tarea: Ganar la loteria.
2 - Tarea: Encontrar moneda de 3 euros.
```

Y tengo 3 usuarios:

```
 1 - Pepe
 2 - Juan
 3 - Ernesto
```

Entonces asigno asigno a `Pepe y Juan` la tarea de `ganar la loteria` y a `Ernesto` la de `encontrar moneda de 3 euros`.

En este momento que les he asignado la tarea, el campo: `finish_date` esta `null` ya que aun no han completado la tarea.

Cuando `Pepe` `gane la loteria` , esta tarea seguira aun sin terminar porque no todos los usuarios asignados a esta `han ganado la loteria` (Queda `Juan` por ganarla para todos los users de esa tarea hayan cumplido su cometido) en cambio en la tarea de `encontrar una moneda de 3euros.` como `ernesto` es el unico que se le ha asignado, en cuanto la cumpla esa tarea estara finalizada.

Comment: Agrega las definiciones que hiciste de las relaciones en cada modelo por favor

Comment: @BetaM listo beta

Comment: Entonces quieres obtener a los usuarios siempre y cuando tengan la misma tarea asignada y la hayan completado todos?

Comment: Si, eso es, pero en vez de querer  obtener a los usuarios como dices, quiero obtener la tarea en si que cumpla dicha condicion. He estado intentando cosas pero no doy con la tecla. Aunque sea una condicion referida a los usuarios, al fin y al cabo quiero retornas las tarjetas que cumplan eso

Answer (score 2):

**Nota importante**

> La funcionalidad de esta respuesta esta basada en que se este usando una versión de [Laravel 7 o superior](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L536) que es desde donde fue introducido el método usado en esta *propuesta*

La clase `BelongsToMany` posee uno de varios métodos para establecer *constraints* al momento de definir la relación en X modelo.

Para este caso el método indicado sería `wherePivotNotNull` que nos ayudará a establecer dicha claúsula para la *tabla pivot*:

```
public function wherePivotNotNull($column, $boolean = 'and')
```

Entonces modifica tu relación definida así:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'tasks_x_users')
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->wherePivotNotNull('finish_date')
                ->withPivot('finish_date');
}
```

**Anexo**

Como dejaba en los comentarios:

> Puedes tener dos consultas está inicial que filtre y otra general como la que ya está hecha y dependiendo de lo que el usuario invoque ejecutar una u otra.

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [**Filtering Queries Via Intermediate Table Columns**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns)
- La clase `BelongsToMany` ubicada en `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`

Comment: No es una restriccion, los usuarios cuando se le asigne una tarea, la relacion nxm entre dicha tarea y usuario se creara con el finish_date a null, me interesa saber que esta null pues significa que se le ha asignado pero aun no lo ha terminado, una vez que el user indique que ha terminado, actualizo el campo al dia en el q este, por eso el campo puede y debe ser nulo en el momento de crear la relacion

Comment: Puedes tener dos consultas está inicial que filtre y otra general como la que ya está hecha y dependiendo de lo que el usuario invoque ejecutar una u otra

Comment: pero si pongo en la relacion eso que me has indicado y quiero hacer un `$task->users` no alterara la que ya tenia no ? solo se altera en caso que lo indique posteriormente en la propia query no?

Comment: Lo que te estoy colocando como respuesta solo filtra la columna deseada excluyendo aquellos registros de dicha columna que no sean nulos

Comment: entonces creo que no es lo que pretendo, voy a poner un ejemplo practico en la pregunta

Comment: he añadido una breve explicacion de como funcionaria o como quiero que funcione. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La tabla pivote `tasks_x_users` solamente entra en juego cuando el   builder (`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`) intenta acceder el modelo que está al otro lado del `belongsToMany`. Esto implica que al hacer

```
 $tasks = Task::with('users')->get()
```

Lo que obtienes tiene la forma de un array donde cada elemento a su vez dice algo como:

```
 {
  id: 1234
  title: 'Ganar la lotería'
  active: true
  users: [{
    id: 1
    name: 'Juanito',
    task_x_users: {
      id: 108
      task_id: 1234
      user_id: 1
      finish_date: 2020-12-01
    }
  },{
    id: 2
    name: 'Pedrito'
    task_x_users: {
      id: 109
      task_id: 1234
      user_id: 2
      finish_date: null
    }
  }]
}
```

Vale decir que una tarea tiene muchos usuarios a través del producto cruz con     *task_x_users*. Cada usuario que sale de ese producto se relaciona con una y solo una tarea a través de *task_x_users*, por lo que `users` es un array y en cada uno de ellos `task_x_users` es un registro específico.

Las tareas sin usuario asignado igual tiene un array `users`, sólo que sin elementos. En principio, entonces, no sólo pides el listado con usuarios sino sujeto a que tenga usuarios:

```
  $data = Task::with('users') // traer el usuario
    ->whereHas('users')       // de entre las tareas con usuarios
    ->get();
```

(de las tareas que tienen usuarios, traer el usuario, dentro del cual viene el pivote) obtienes todos los registros en la forma de una colección (1). Con esto vienen todas las tareas con algún usuario asignado en el status que sea. Nada garantiza que sean tareas completadas.

**Solución burda pero funcional**

Sobre el conjunto completo de las tareas con usuario puedes aplicar un filtro

```
   $data = $data->filter(function($tarea) {
      foreach($tarea->users as $user) {  // recorro el array users de cada tarea
        if(
          $user
            ->task_x_users
            ->finish_date===null) {  // si cualquier pivote tiene finish date nula
           return false;             // la tarea completa queda fuera del filtro
        }
      }
      return true;
   });
```

Y eso también es una colección (2). Ahora, esta solución es subóptima y poco intuitiva a simple vista, pero la dejo porque siempre en caso de duda se puede filtrar, mapear y reducir una colección aunque sea menos eficiente.

**Solución correcta:**

Siempre partiendo de la consulta base (`with('users')->whereHas('users')`) podrías traer sólo aquellos donde el pivote tenga `finish_date`, usando el segundo parámetro del `whereHas` ([querying-relationship-existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)) (3)

```
  $data = Task->with('users')           
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) {
       $query->whereNotNull('task_x_users.finish_date');
    })->get();
```

O sea "aquellas tareas que tienen usuarios relacionados mediante un pivote cuyo  `finish_date` es no nulo". Pero, si lo pensamos bien, esto se trae las tareas donde *al menos* un usuario la ha completado aunque los demás asignados la tengan pendiente.

La solución, en cambio, es la fórmula:

```
  $data = Task->with('users') // treaer el usuario
    -> whereHas('users')      // de entre las tareas con usuarios
    ->whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) {  // donde ningún pivote
       $query->whereNull('task_x_users.finish_date'); // tenga finish date nulo
    })->get();
```

Si una tarea tiene usuarios, y de entre ellos ninguno tiene finish_date nulo, entonces es una tarea 100% completada.

**Método de [BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam)**

Parece que `wherePivotNotNull` no está en la versión de Laravel con que probé, pero de todos modos, su solución es muy práctica porque encapsula el filtro de tareas completadas permitiendo, de este modo, su reutilización.

Lo que él estaría proponiendo podrías implementarlo con una relación paralela a tu `users` actual:

```
public function all_users_done()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'tasks_x_users')
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->wherePivot('finish_date','!=',null)
                ->withPivot('finish_date');
}
```

Y luego obtener el resultado con

```
Task::with('all_users_done')->whereHas('all_users_done');
```

**Usando scopes**

Declarando un método en Task tal que

```
public function scopeFinished($query) {
  return $query->with('users')
         ->whereHas('users')
          ->whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) {  
           $query->whereNull('task_x_users.finish_date');
        });
}
```

estarás añadiendo la condición deseada a cualquier query relacionada con tareas, de modo que evites añadir las cláusulas una y otra vez.(`finished` viene de quitarle al método la palabra `scope` y cambiar la letra que sigue a minúscula). Sobre esta query prefiltrada que funciona como quien dice similar a una vista, puedes hacer todas las otras operaciones que quieras.

```
   Task::finished()
     ->with(...)
     ->take(...)
     ->orderBy(...)
```

---

Notas:

1. Esta colección es del tipo `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`
2. Esta colección es del tipo `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` ( superclase del tipo de colección en la nota anterior)
3. La función del segundo parámetro espera como argumento una instancia de `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` pero eso es anecdótico.

Comment: Con que versión de Laravel probaste?

Comment: la 7, pero a lo mejor me falta implementar una interfaz o extender de otro modelo?

Comment: revisé en el repo del framework y el método que propongo también esta presente en la versión 7, [checa aquí](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php)

Comment: uff, parece que tengo la 6, necesito actualizar ese proyecto :plaf

Comment: Es bueno que hayas hecho la observación, asi noté también que es la versión 6 donde aún no existía ;), editaré mi respuesta para agregar ese detalle